# wpf DataContext error in Designer

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid, designer

I have a presentation involving (3) DataGrids that are *almost* the same, but different enough that it seems like a cleaner design to do just the whole thing in code.

It is still raw (class diagram below), but works the way I want except for one thing! The visual studio designer can't figure out the late binding of the DataContext, so it throws an error.

An example of how I am pulling the grid's data context for use in a given column is below, as well as the error I get.

1. Does s anyone see a way to make the designer happy with the existing code?
2. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better approach?

I know there are ways to give Blend some notion of data but I don't as yet know Blend.

Cheers,
Berryl

## CODE

```
public abstract class TimesheetGridColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    ...

    protected ActivityCollectionViewModel _GetDataContext() { return (ActivityCollectionViewModel) DataGridOwner.DataContext; }

    public virtual void SetHeader() {
        var tb = new TextBlock
                 {
                     Text = _GetHeaderText(),
                     ToolTip = _GetHeaderToolTip(),
                 };
        Header = tb;
    }
    ....
}

public class ActivityDescriptionColumn : TimesheetGridColumn
{
    ...

    *** WORKS at RUNTIME but DESIGNER does not know that ******* 
    protected override string _GetHeaderText() { 
        return _GetDataContext().PresentationSubject; 
    }

}
```

## XAML SNIPPET & DESIGNER ERROR

```
<Expander Header="{Binding DisplayName}" BorderThickness="1" IsExpanded="True">

    <dataGrid:ActivityDataGrid /> <=============== simple but error

</Expander>

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at ...ColumnSubclasses.ActivityDescriptionColumn._GetHeaderText() in ActivityDescriptionColumn.cs:line 24
```

## CLASS DIAGRAM

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to get the designer to work again, you can probably put a `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode`check in somewhere.

How about:

```
protected override string _GetHeaderText()  
    {  
        if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))  
        {  
            return _GetDataContext().PresentationSubject;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            return "Design Mode Text";  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to solve your designer problem with the Designer Attributes that are a part of WPF.  Follow [this link to an MSDN article on Design-time attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839627.aspx) and look specifically at the d:DataContext attribute. If you can create a sample implementation  of the class that your grids are binding to, you may be able to get the designer working for you again.